# mongoose middleware, show length of array in model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I want to get the size of array in the model:

```js
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true },
    items: { type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId], default: [] },
  },
  {
    toJSON : {
      virtuals : true
    },
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


UserSchema.virtual("itemsCount").get(function () {
  return this.items.length;
});

module.exports = {
  UserModel: mongoose.model("user", UserSchema ),
};
```

```js
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    owner: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,required: true, ref:"user" 
 },
  },
  {
    toJSON : {
      virtuals : true
    },
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


module.exports = {
  ProductModel: mongoose.model("product", ProductSchema ),
};
```

But I want to hide *items* in the output whenever I try to use projection it gives an error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

```js
const newPosts = await ProductModel.find({}).populate([{ path: "owner",  select: { itemsCount: 0 }}]);
```

if I don't use `select` it works:

```js
const newPosts = await ProductModel.find({}).populate([{ path: "owner" }}]);
```

But I don't want to show `items` filed in output

Comment: what is `itemsCount`? You need to use `this.items` instead.

Comment: You are right, I wrote it wrong here, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Can you tell me which Schema have you added in the question here. `Schema` doesnt tell if its `Product` or `User` schema

Comment: its UserSchema @RaviShankarBharti

Comment: Can you also show your ProductSchema, That will help me in writing the exact solution you need.

Comment: Perhaps `select: '-itemsCount'`?

Comment: here you are @RaviShankarBharti

Comment: didn't work @robertklep

Comment: @EmmaTeylor Can you make sure your question is properly typed and correct, cause if you have `owner` in Schema, you cant do `user` in populate.

Comment: i'm sorry, fixed @RaviShankarBharti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline for this:

```
ProductModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "users"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: "$name",
      "users": {
        itemsCount: {
          $size: "$users.items"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Read more about [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to understand.

Here is the Mongodb playground to see the results: https://mongoplayground.net/p/R0ZQiV8I-YM

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that's right, but I used *populate* for some reason, is there a way to do that with *populate* ?

Comment: Please check if my updated answer works for you.

Comment: Thank it works, but is there any way to do it with mongoose middleware not aggregate?